# Is there anything to gain after resetting a planet?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

Before everbody thinks this is a noob question, I'm not talking about angel investors. I'm talking about the reset button in the Stats tab in the career menu.

So after resetting, you lose all your angels and money but keep the earned mega bucks, gold and planet- and platinum multipliers.
I was offered to reset the moon for the second time now and decided to do so.

First thing I noticed is that the multipliers were still active, which is nice. But now I already almost finished the moon completely for the second time but did not gain anything real in exchange (except some fun).

So my question is, If I reset a planet is there anything additional to gain? For example, some extra gold, Mega bucks, multipliers or perhaps even suits or badges or other types of swag.

Comment: Note: Said reset button only shows up after completing a planet and disappears after activating until you completed that planet again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this kind of reset is only to give you something to do while you're waiting for your earth to finish.

That said: When you finish the earth, you have the option to reset it to gain 5000 gold. You're basically done with the game at this point, but if you feel like pressing on or get a head start on any events, these 5000 might come in handy.